# php jsoncallback undefined

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cordova

Initially everything works fine until the IT guy changed server.
I use ajax to call php file to get data from database.  Now im getting an error **PHP Notice:  Undefined index: jsoncallback**

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $records = array();
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $records[] = $row;  
        }
      }

      mysqli_close($conn);



    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';

====


      $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://test.php',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                    async: false,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data, status)
                    {
                    },
  error: function(){}
  });
```

Comment: i noticed if i do  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users id=1"; then it works

Comment: where you had executed the query ? i couldn't found it.

Comment: sorry i did execute $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  i noticed when it returns a lot of data its not returning any data

Comment: when i do $sql = "SELECT * FROM stores LIMIT 10" it doesn't work.  but lesser then 10 records it returns details

Comment: after executing the query is it gives to some results or not . And Please update your question also .

Comment: after executing the query it only gives results if there are not a lot of data.  I'm not sure is it because the array is too large it doesn't work

Comment: In the ajax request you didn't passed any data parameter of jsoncallback .Then why you are trying to get it in php file ?

Comment: *"until the IT guy changed server"* – Well then, talk to your IT guy. Perhaps he's rewriting the URLs, or stripping query parameters on a load balancer or something…

Comment: sorry i don't understand, can you give me an example.

Comment: i managed to get data returned but depends on the data, it seems like might be a data conflict

Comment: I found the issue, it has nothing to do with the code but its because users entered in a wierd single quote hence causes a conflict.  When change to a normal single quote it works as required.  Thanks guys for your input